# How do I copy existing HTML text into a new section using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to write an XSLT script that will copy the text that's within this section `<section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section" data-title="Feedback">` from the html below:

```
<ol class="ktp-answer-set"> 
  <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">“I cough in the morning, but it stops.”
    <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude"> 
      <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section" data-title="Feedback"> 
        <p>Captopril is an angiotensin-converting enzyme inhibitor (ACE-I) that has a dry, hacking, persistent cough as an adverse effect. The client reports a morning cough that may or may not be associated with the medication.</p> 
      </section> 
    </section> 
  </li>  
  <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">“I am waiting to learn the results of my pregnancy test.”
    <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude"> 
      <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section" data-title="Feedback"> 
        <p>ACE-Is are contraindicated in pregnancy. There is a black box warning that states ACE-I can cause injury and even death to a developing fetus. Since the client reports waiting for the results of a pregnancy test, this should be reported immediately to the health care provider.</p> 
      </section> 
    </section> 
  </li> 
</ol>
```

into a new section that looks like this:

```
<section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section atom-exclude"> 
  <p class="atom-exclude">1) 
    <span class="mark-false">INCORRECT</span> – Captopril is an angiotensin-converting enzyme inhibitor (ACE-I) that has a dry, hacking, persistent cough as an adverse effect. The client reports a morning cough that may or may not be associated with the medication.
  </p>  
  <p class="atom-exclude">2) 
    <span class="mark-true">CORRECT</span> – ACE-Is are contraindicated in pregnancy. There is a black box warning that states ACE-I can cause injury and even death to a developing fetus. Since the client reports waiting for the results of a pregnancy test, this should be reported immediately to the health care provider.
  </p> 
</section>
```

What do I need to include in my XSLT script to duplicate that text into a new section? And can I number each one with 1), 2), etc?

Below the stylesheet I was given to work with:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation']">
        <xsl:param name="content-item-name"/>

        <!-- Tab 1: Decision Tree -->  
        <section>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$content-item-name = $input-qid">

            <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback"
                class="ktp-explanation-section atom-exclude">
                <xsl:for-each select="//xhtml:section[property='ktp:explanation-section']/p">
                    <p class="atom-exclude">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </section>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Feedback']"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose> 
        </section>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is your current (minimal, please) XSLT?

Comment: Where do I find that info (I'm very new XSLT)?

Comment: Also do note that text from expected output doesn't match text from input source.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I copied the output from a file that already has the correct output. The output here is only a sample of what I actually need.

Comment: _"What do I need to include in my XSLT script to duplicate that text into a new section?"_ That inclusion would involve to know your current stylesheet.

Comment: I just added the stylesheet I was given.

Comment: That stylesheet for sure is not minimal... From what I can see, you want to output **those `p` elements** in the context of **one `section` element** with  `@property` attrib ute equal to `"ktp:explanation"` value. If that's the case, you would need to traverse back to `ol` ancestor and then for each `//xhtml:section[property="ktp:explanation-section"]/p` output the **new** `p` with the `span` and the apply templates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207007/discussion-between-mjwolff1-and-alejandro).